# Functions of CPU

Tags: computer-architecture

What part of the CPU communicates with all the other parts of the processor and makes the processor faster by containing frequently used data or instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: [The cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache)

From Wikipedia:

> A CPU cache is a hardware cache used by the central processing unit (CPU) of a computer to reduce the average cost (time or energy) to access data from the main memory. A cache is a smaller, faster memory, located closer to a processor core, which stores copies of the data from frequently used main memory locations. Most CPUs have different independent caches, including instruction and data caches, where the data cache is usually organized as a hierarchy of more cache levels (L1, L2, L3, L4, etc.).

Comment: I downvoted because: you answered an obvious homework question.

Comment: Communities on StackExchange grow and foster from good questions, good answers, critical discussion, and upvotes. Downvotes and accusations takes the community in the wrong direction.

Comment: Downvoting content that should not be on the community improves the community.